# How to create long term stock for Bacillus subtilis?

Tags: bacteriology, cell-culture, growth-media

I am trying to create a long-term stock for Bacillus subtilis (Bacterial glycerol stocks). I have looked online for guides and step-by-step tutorials and I found that they don't say where the sample originally comes from.
In my case, I am using **Bacillus subtilis subsp. subtilis (ATCC® 23857™)** pure from the supplier bottle.

What is the proper procedure to create a long-term stock for Bacillus subtilis using this product?

Comment: I worked with *B. subtilis* WB800 and just used 50% glycerol / 50% LB. I imagine the same would work fine with wild-type.

Comment: Do you add the bacteria in the LB before mixing with the glycerol?

Comment: No I would prepare the glycerol/LB mixture and autoclave it then create the stocks from log-phase (approximately) plate cultures.

Comment: @canadianer Wouldn't you want to use liquid cultures as the source so you can count the number of cells? Or does *B. subtilis* not grow in suspension? I come from the world of eukaryotic (mostly mammalian) cell culture, so I honestly don't know...

Comment: @MattDMo They certainly do grow in liquid culture, but I’ve never used one to make glycerol stocks. Perhaps some do it more carefully than I do but, in my experience, this method was sufficient for my application (protein expression). I imagine mammalian cells are a lot more finicky.

Comment: @canadianer Can you turn your comments into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Comment: @jakebeal Sure thing, although I’m not sure how helpful it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked with *Bacillus subtilis* WB800 and just used 50% glycerol / 50% LB. I imagine the same would work fine with wild-type. I would prepare the glycerol/LB mixture and autoclave it then create the stocks from log-phase (approximately) plate cultures. This method was sufficient for my application (protein expression).